# 404 NOT FOUND error

Tags: 2010

Last week, I did an in-place upgrade of my SharePoint 2010 Foundation server, from Server 2012 R2 to Server 2019. Ever since then, I am unable to open files of any type that are over a certain size. I have narrowed the size to between 5097 KB (works) and 5192 KB (doesn't work). This affects PDF and PPTX, and probably other large file types as well.

The "404 NOT FOUND" error happens when opening files through the browser. When opening files through Webdav, I get a different error message, such as "Adobe Acrobat could not open 'FILENAME' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged." for a PDF.

My gut instinct is that a setting was changed in SharePoint or IIS during the upgrade. I've been searching Google for solution for about a week, and the most common suggestion is to check and increase the various file size limits.

In web.config, I have set maxAllowedContentLength=2147483647.

In applicationHost.config, I have set maxAllowedContentLength=1073741824 (I left it as it was).

In the ISS logs, I see this series of events (removed the filename as it is confidential) when I try to open a file:

```
Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:FILENAME))    
Name=Request (GET:FILENAME) 3106c6c5-4199-41c3-a7bc-0af45331e2c8
af71    Medium      HTTP Request method: GET    3106c6c5-4199-41c3-a7bc-0af45331e2c8
Overridden HTTP request method: GET 3106c6c5-4199-41c3-a7bc-0af45331e2c8
HTTP request URL: FILENAME URL  3106c6c5-4199-41c3-a7bc-0af45331e2c8
Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:FILENAME)). Execution Time=5.9737 3106c6c5-4199-41c3-a7bc-0af45331e2c8
```

Is there anything else I can try? Some of the documents that are inaccessible are quite important.

Comment: Have you change the SQL server too? Were on SharePoint SQL instance enabled RBS or something like this? Have you configured RBS Provider correctly on the new environment? You need also configure RBS connectors on SharePoint servers.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct, you did an inplace upgrade of the underlying operating system from Windows Server 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2019?

This scenario is absolutely not supported. Performing an OS inplace-upgrade itself is a very bad-practise. [SharePoint 2010 got support for Windows Server 2012 R2 with ServicePack 2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2724471/sharepoint-2010-support-for-windows-server-2012-and-windows-server-201). It was never built to be run on any newer versions of Windows.

Consider restoring your server from a previous backup.

Comment: Unfortunately you do understand correctly. It was a silly thing to do, but it is now too late to go back. I'm just thinking that there must be some setting that is limiting it to around 5MB, even if it was the unsupported OS upgrade that forced the change.

Comment: Good luck on that :( Try to go back to the old server. It is to be feared that this will not be the only problem you need to solve on your own.